# How to remove a row from a matrix inside a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a cell array (A) with size of 400 x 1 and each cell of this array includes a matrix with size 9 x 4. As such, it looks like this:

```
A={[9x4 double];[9x4 double];...;[9x4 double]};
```

Now, I want to remove the zero rows from these sub matrices and then obtain a new `A` cell array called `A_new` where its sub matrices don't have any zero rows like this:

```
A_new={[5x4 double];[7x4 double];...;[4x4 double]};
```

By my below code, I can find the index of rows which are not zero but I couldn't create my cell array like I mentioned above. This is my written code and for the bold part, I have a problem and I couldn't solve it.

```
  for i=1:A_Length
     [row,col]=find(A{i,1});
     out=[row col];
     NNZ_row=unique(row);
     Length_NNZ= length(NNZ_row);
  for j=1:Length_NNZ
     **A_NonZero{i,1}= ??????????**
  end
```

end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is take each cell, then use [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) on the **opposite** of the matrix over all of the columns in each row to determine which rows contain all zeroes.  Once you do this, use these locations and remove those rows from this matrix and save this to your new matrix.

As such, do this:

```
A_new = cell(1,numel(A));
for i=1:numel(A)
   mat = A{i};
   ind = all(~mat, 2);
   A_new{i} = mat(~ind,:);
end
```

The first line of code creates a new cell array that is the same size as `A`.  Next, for each element in `A`, extract the matrix at each cell location, use `all` on the opposite of this matrix to find those elements that we need to keep, then save this new matrix into the corresponding location in `A_new`.

If you want to do this in a single line of code, use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
A_new = cellfun(@(x) x(~all(~x,2),:), A, 'uni', 0);
```

The first argument to `cellfun` is an anonymous function that performs what the `for` loop was doing.  We find those rows that contain all zeroes and use those to remove the rows in each matrix in the cell array.  The second argument is the matrix we want to operate on, which is `A`.  The `'uni'` and `0` flags are important because the outputs are not single values but matrices, and so the output of this function will be a cell array that is the same size as `A` where each element is the matrix for those corresponding locations in `A` with the zero rows removed.

Comment: THX for your comprehensive answer. Both your suggested methods work fine . I prefer to use the your first suggestion

Comment: @user3185893 - My pleasure.  I did the first approach as you already had a loop in your code.  I just modified it to suit your algorithm.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a combination of `cellfun` and `any`:

```
A_new = cellfun(@(x) x(any(x~=0,2),:), A, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: THX. it works fine. But the other answer fits me more. THX again for your correct answer